# play framework 2.0 - unexpected exception - Key Not Found : Source

Tags: playframework

I'm getting a key not found error message while trying to start my Play 2.0 app. I actually think that I did not change anything, and this error just popped-up. Actually I did one thing. I opened the files in the folder target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed/main and closed it (I did not changed anything, nor saved or deleted a file). But after reloading the app I got this error. Any idea what I can do?

> [info] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000...
>
> (Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
>
> [error]
>   {file:/Volumes/INPROG/03_Projects/06_Play_Applications/Space-for-Art/}Space-for-Art/compile:sources:
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE [error]
>   application -
>
> ! Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->
>
> play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception
>   [NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE]   at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:228)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221)
>   ~[na:na]  at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]   at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:221)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$3$$anonfun$2.apply(PlayReloader.scala:219)
>   ~[na:na]  at scala.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:183)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2] java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not
>   found: SOURCE     at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:224)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$.default(Map.scala:87)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]   at
>   scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:135)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$.apply(Map.scala:87)
>   ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]   at
>   play.templates.GeneratedSource.source(ScalaTemplates.scala:145)
>   ~[templates_2.9.1.jar:2.0]    at
>   play.templates.GeneratedSource.sync(ScalaTemplates.scala:154)
>   ~[templates_2.9.1.jar:2.0]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Execute

```
play clean update
```

to refresh the compiled files. And then run:

```
play run
```

That should solve it

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. What does the update command execute? I found out that clean does the following:
Delete temporary files (including the bytecode cache) .. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: Update tries to pull all the dependencies in the project again. The compiled code could get corrupted due to some bug, who knows...doesn't happen often though