# Play application - Push rejected in Heroku

Tags: heroku, github, playframework-2.0, sbt

I created a Play application and I pushed it to heroku using

```
  git push heroku master
```

That worked.

Then I pushed it to my github account

```
  git push -u origin master
```

That worked.

I made a minor code change in my application and it works fine in my local machine. When I tried to push to Heroku using the steps:

```
  git add .
  git commit -m "comments"
  git push heroku master
```

It breaks with the message:

```
   [info] Set current project to MyProjectX (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
   java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE
   at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
   at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
   at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
   ....
   ....
   ....
   [error] (compile:managedSources) java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: SOURCE
   [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Mar 14, 2014 9:47:42 PM
   !     Failed to build app with sbt

   !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Scala app

    To git@heroku.com:MyProjectX.git
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:MyProjectX.git'
```

I'm not sure why it broke suddenly when I pushed it to heroku. Is it some conflict with github? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [play framework 2.0 - unexpected exception - Key Not Found : Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10574514/play-framework-2-0-unexpected-exception-key-not-found-source)

Comment: Also see https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2263

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `play.Project` with `sbt.Project` in Build.scala fixed it for me.

See also https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2263#issuecomment-36190502

Before:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
```

After:

```
val main = sbt.Project(id = appName, base = file("."))
  .settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true should fix this issue

more at [Heroku Help Page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support#clean-builds)